# Bounded function approximated by simple function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function $f$ a bounded function on $X$. Is there always a sequence of simple functions $\{\varphi_n\}$ that converges to $f$?(My thoughts: since the values of simple function is countable and non-measurable bounded function has uncountable values, so the answer is no. ).

My question: is there a sequence of simple functions $\{\varphi_n\}$ such that 
$$\sup\{\varphi_n\}=f，\text{ and }\forall \varphi_n\leq f$$

---

$\varphi$ is Simple function  provided that $\varphi$ has only finite values on $X$ and can be expressed as $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{E_i}$, where $X=\sqcup_{i=1}^nE_i$

---

**Example** consider following $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$:
$$f=
\begin{cases}
1, & x\in A\\
0, & x\in A^c
\end{cases}$$
where $A$ is non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$.
How to construct $\{\varphi_n\}$ for this $f$?

Comment: How do you define "simple function"?  One such type of approximation involves approximating continuous functions with piecewise constant ones, but this may not be what you have in mind.

Comment: @hardmath A function with finite values

Comment: So are you asking for approximation of a bounded function by a "function with finitely many values" (a finite range) in the $\sup$-norm?  I think this is a pretty standard construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall assume that you are talking about finding a sequence of simple measurable  functions $\phi_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\phi_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise, where $f$ is a given measurable function.

This is indeed possible.

For instance we can define:

$$A_{n,k}:=f^{-1}([k\cdot 2^{-n},(k+1)\cdot 2^{-n}))$$

where $k,n$ are non-negative integers.

Each of these sets will be measurable (since $f$ is measurable), and for each $n$, we have $\cup_k A_{n,k}=X$.

We then define

$$\phi_{n}(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot 2^{-n}\cdot 1_{A_{n,k}}(x).$$

Since $f$ is bounded, each of these sums is finite, and consequently each $\phi_n$ is simple. Moreover we have $0\leq f-\phi_n(x) < 2^{-n}$, so we have constructed a sequence of simple functions with the desired property.

(Remark: Boundedness of $f$ is not important, a minor modification to the proof allows us to drop this assumption.)

Comment: I think rather it is *measurable* that can be dropped, rather than bounded.

Comment: Actually, I don't assume $f$ measurable.

Comment: Okay, well dropping $f$ measurable reduces the work, as our simple functions are then surely not required to be measurable simple functions.

Boundedness certainly can be dropped. In taking the sum for $\phi_n$, we terminate at the first $k$ larger than $3^n$ for instance.

Comment: How would you approximate $f(x) = 1/x$ when $x\in (0,1]$, zero elsewhere?  Any finite number of values will fail to approximate the unbounded function $f(x)$ within (say) $1$.

Comment: We don't make any claim about uniform approximation, (although we get this in the bounded case), just about pointwise convergence.

At what point $x\in(0,1]$ does my construction of $\phi_n$ fail to converge to $1/x$ ?

Comment: I see. I misinterpreted the mention of $\sup$ in the Question as calling for convergence in the $\sup$-norm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, if by "simple" you mean a function taking only finitely many values. (I assume that $0\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$.)

Example: $\varphi_n=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{\{k2^{-n}< f\le(k+1)2^{-n}\}}$?

Comment: How about this function: choose $A\subset [0,1]$,$A$ is non-measurable, $f(x)=1,\forall x\in A$,and $f(x)=0,\forall x\in [0,1]-A$?